# Flask app vercel give error 404 when deploy

Tags: python, flask, vercel

I am trying to deploy on Vercel. However, when I visit the URL of the deployed app, I get a 404 error. I have tried adjusting the Vercel configuration file vercel.json and the Flask app app.py, but I am still encountering the error.

this is my file structure:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCw8Q.png)

this is my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

this is vercel.json

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "./app.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/static(.*)",
      "dest": "/static"
    }
  ]
}
```

in my log:

WARN! Due to `builds` existing in your configuration file, the Build and Development Settings defined in your Project Settings will not apply. Learn More: https://vercel.link/unused-build-settings

app:https://dji-mini-3-pro-landing-page-lbzqmv47f-irfanizz01s-projects.vercel.app/

this is my github file:https://github.com/irfanizz01/DJI-mini-3-pro-landing-page